# How to indicate certain overloaded function?

Tags: c++

For example we have some c++ code where some function execute another function with some parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename F>
void todo(const T& param, const F& function)
{
  function(param);
}

void foo(int a)
{
  cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int iA = 1051;

  todo(iA, foo);

  return 0;
}
```

But if we add one more function with name `foo`

```
void foo(double a)
{
  cout << a << endl;
}
```

Then compiler don't know to which one function generate template.

**!!! Important !!!**

*This isn't real code, it's just example. Problem concretely in pass reloaded function as argument.*

**Does anyone know how to indicate certain function explicitly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
todo(iA, static_cast<void (*)(int)>(&foo));
```

is one way, at the expense of readability at the call site.

Test code (retaining your 2 character indentation - I am a Myrmidon):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename F>
void todo(const T& param, const F& function)
{
  function(param);
}
void foo(double a)
{
  cout << "double " << a << endl;
}

void foo(int a)
{
  cout << "int " << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int iA = 1051;

  todo(iA, static_cast<void (*)(int)>(&foo));
  todo(iA, static_cast<void (*)(double)>(&foo));

  return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
int 1051
double 1051
```

See https://www.ideone.com/DEiLBE

Comment: Well, simple `static_cast` also works. I'm glad to read better answers, they show me I've got so much yet to learn :)

Comment: As I know `static_cast` - is dynamic polymorphism, but templates is static, it will not work.

Comment: @KirillRud: This is the idiomatic way, unless I need a very large cup of coffee.

Comment: @KirillRud - The static in the static cast kinda implies it's not dynamic. And frankly, you can give Bathsheba (who knows a fair few things about C++) the benefit of the doubt, and try.

Comment: @StoryTeller Seriously, did you try to understand the problem before writing a comment?
1. This is a too limited solution, in this case it will work only with void functions.
2. This will not work, how can you pass a reference to `foo` if the compiler does not know which `foo` you mean?

Comment: @KirillRud - I understand the problem you presented perfectly. As does everybody here who tried to help you. So far it is only you who flashes his ignorance on the subject with confidence. If you feel you presented your problem poorly, then by all means revise your question.

Comment: @KirillRud and now you're annoying. No one can _guess_ the limitation of your specific case **unless** you write an [mcve]. And I'd like to emphasis _complete_!

Comment: @StoryTeller While he did not write a full example - it was extremely incomprehensible how to use all this. But I'll be frank, he did the best job, unlike you and unlike you YSC. It is impossible to know everything on this, so only you can be ignorant - without knowing the manners.

Comment: @YSC Yes, no one knows, so they made comments, which could be corrected and clarified. Thank you for your absolutely important comment.

Comment: @KirillRud - You are absolutely right. It's impossible to know everything about C++. Doesn't at all change your little presentation of ignorance however. Or your complete lack of civility.

Comment: @StoryTeller Moreover, if already there was such a question - skinte the link, and do not just report it.

Comment: @KirillRud - I suggest you visit the [help] and learn how the site works before advising anyone.

Comment: @StoryTeller I see no reason to continue the conversation with you, please do not spam.
P.S.
Quote.
"marked as duplicate by StoryTeller c++ 1 hour ago

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If  those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."
Proof
http://paste.pics/2BRIJ

Answer (score 3):

```
auto identifier = type{value}
```

This is the syntax suggested by Sutter Mill in its [AAA (Almost Always Auto) Guru of the Week #94](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) when one needs to commit to a specific type.

It perfectly applies here:

```
int iA = 1051;

using foo_int_type = void(*)(int);
auto non_ambiguous_int_foo = foo_int_type{foo};
todo(iA, non_ambiguous_int_foo);
```

[Live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43bf5b42bfad5f30)

Comment: Good idea, but it will not work in case if function return different type except void.

Comment: @KirillRud - You've made several comments already, so I feel I just must ask this: Where are you getting all of this from?

Comment: @KirillRud of course, you need to explicitly use the type of the overload you wish to use. If you need to qualify `bool foo(int)`, you'd need to define your type as `bool(*)(int)`, etc.

Comment: @YSC
Suppose you have a large list of functions that you need to pass as arguments. Each of them returns different value types, but some are overloaded. In the latter case, the problem arises, because the use of the template requires an explicit transfer of parameters. So if you have overloaded functions, you need to specify them explicitly.

Comment: @YSC If you make your template for each return value, then creating a universal call function will not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static_cast` to select the right function overload. For example: `todo(iA, static_cast<void(&)(double)>(foo))`

Comment: As I know `static_cast` - is dynamic polymorphism, but templates is static, it will not work.

Comment: @Kirill Rud `static_cast` has several functions. The one I showed here is rarely used but it exists and is absolutely correct. Furthermore, as its name suggests it's purpose is to do "things" statically. The cases when it can be used to work with polymorphic classes are only those when all the information necessary to perform a cast is available at compile time that is there is no virtual inheritance. Also, YSC answered you with a different technique (also correct) wich under the hood involves a `static_cast`.